# Edit layer property when another layer is activated

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-scripting

I successfully created my first fitness sleeveless t-shirt mockup using Photoshop CC.

This is the result so far:

[image]

It's my first mockup ever and I'm pretty satisfied with this result.

There is an issue when I change the shirt colour to black; as you can see, there are too many lights and the resulting mockup seems fake:

[image]

These are my layers:

[image]

The issue with the black colour is that the `lights` layer is too opaque, so I need to decrease its opacity to 5% to make it work and not seem super-fake.

Is there a way to tell Photoshop to change `lights`' layer opacity when layer `Black Opal` is activated and revert it back when it's deactivated?

Comment: Doesn't look fake to me at all. It looks like a polyester stretch top, pretty similar to a few that I myself use for working out. Of course, if it's meant to look like cotton, then it doesn't work. But it doesn't look _fake_ to me, just looks like a different material. (So does the white version, though.)

Answer (score 0):

To be honest, for clothing I would just use shadow layer. I would drop the lights layer completely. and it will work a charm with every colour. As it makes your singlet look too fake / silky.

The only tricky colour is black, so instead of using pure black and adding lights to it, I would just use very dark grey like #161616 or so.

It's less complicated, and gives better and more consistent outcome.

lights layer is very useful for items that reflect light much more. Like plastic, shiny clothing (like silk) etc.

very quick job would look like this (I would work on the shadows a bit more to make the outcome look more closely to the kind of material are you looking for. 
[image: Quick Singlets mock-up]

Answer (score -1):

Duplicate the **lights** Layer.
Put it above the **Black Opal**.
Hold the alt key and click between these two layers(a new icon will appear).
Done.
The effect will only act to the **Black Opal** layer.

Comment: I can't do this. Both `lights` and `shadows`layers have to stay above the `art` layer, while `Black Opal`, `Crimson Red` and `White` have to stay under the `art` layer, otherwise blending will not work. Is there any way to do it via script maybe?